# Pandas dataframe merge gives strange output for a matching column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, etl

Here is the merge that I'm trying.

```
X_context = X_answers.merge(X,on="document_id")
```

I'm checking for 5 document ids in particular.

**`X_answers` -> Verified that this has all 5 document ids mentioned above.**

**`X` -> Verified that this has all 5 document ids mentioned above.**

Both `X_answers` & `X` has the column `document_id`.

But the merge is always excluding those 5 document ids even if those are present in both dataframes (`X_answers` & `X`)

The merge should work and include them if document ids are present in both dataframes. Can someone help me understand whats going wrong here?

Comment: this is strange , did you check the type of the 2 columns document_id

Comment: Can you please add sample data of the two dataframes?

Comment: @you_know_nothing_jon_snow
type of `document_id` in `X_answers` is `float64`, while it is `object` in `X` .
I'm wondering how other document ids (except the 5 document ids mentioned) are getting matched if there's a mismatch in data types.

Comment: According to Pandas' documentation:

If a pandas object contains data with multiple dtypes in a single column, the dtype of the column will be chosen to accommodate all of the data types (object is the most general)

Comment: @you_know_nothing_jon_snow
So, can I make `document_id` to `float64` in both dataframes? I'm guessing that will resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes try this and can you tell me if it's work plz

Comment: @you_know_nothing_jon_snow It is still giving the same merge result even after converting both columns to `float64`.

Comment: what is the shape of your dataframe ? because some type you have 2 colums in the same dataframe with the same name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231726/discussion-between-you-know-nothing-jon-snow-and-rahul-raj).